# PHP: how to iterate through all objects of a class?

Tags: php, class, object

I have a code in which an array contains objects, which have objects in them, for example:

```
<?php
class person {
    public $name;
    public $foods=array();
}
class food {
    public $foodnames=array() ;
}
$peoplearray[$name] = new person;
$peoplearray[$name]->name = 'john' ;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key] = new food;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key]->foodnames[$key] = 'ice cream' ;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key] = new food;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key]->foodnames[$key] = 'banana' ;

$peoplearray[$name] = new person;
$peoplearray[$name]->name = 'julie' ;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key] = new food;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key]->foodnames[$key] = 'chocolate' ;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key] = new food;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key]->foodnames[$key] = 'coffee' ;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key] = new food;
$peoplearray[$name]->foods[$key]->foodnames[$key] = 'rice' ;
?>
```

now i need too iterate through all the objects in class food so i can fetch their properties. anyone knows the most effecient way of doing this?

Comment: It's an array. `foreach()` should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a static property in class food and put your food objects in it at construct time :

```
class food {
  public static $collection = array();
  // other properties ...

  public function __construct() {
    // Stuff
    self::$collection[] = $this;
  }
}

// Create foo objects
$f = new food();

// Iterate
foreach(food::$collection as $foodobj) {
  // Stuff
}
```

Comment: You should also add a `__destruct()` implementation to remove the object from the collection.  I would index the collection using `spl_object_hash($this)`, and then removing from the collection would be straightforward.

Comment: I agree, object destruction should be handled (maybe except if food object will never be destroyed except at script shutdown time ...)